# How to find unsuccessful sent mail in Apple Mail (iCloud email account)?

Tags: macos, apple-mail

I failed to send a mail because of a 30MB attachment. I tried to resend it, but I cannot find it anywhere -- drafts, sent, junk. Outbox doesn't appear.

Is there a way to find unsuccessful sent mail? I don't want to rewrite it.

Comment: Look in your outbox.

Comment: @desbest: is there a difference between "outbox" and "sent items", as in MS-Outlook?

Comment: @Dominique Outbox is an anachronism that dates back to the days of floppy disks and dial-up internet, where you'd wait 30 minutes to download a 5 minute song on 52K speed and you had to connect to the internet sparingly to send your emails, as the landline telephone wasn't usable if you was online, as they shared the same connection. It was more important to receive phone calls than to receive emails. By Microsoft Outlook, do you mean the windows software that has IMAP and SMTP support for every email address in the world, or the outlook.com for remotely hosted `@outlook.com` email addresses.

Comment: @Dominique The outbox is where presumably sent emails appear, before they are sent. In today's era, going under a tunnel on a train.